# how do I find eigenvalues of Cayley graph for one subset given a different subset

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

How do I find eigenvalues for the adjacency matrix of Cayley graph $X(S_n,S)$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n$ and $S$ is the set of transpositions $(i,i+1)$, if the eigenvalues of the graph $X(S_n,T)$ are given by $|T|\chi(1,2)/\chi(i,j)$ with $T$ being the set of transpositions $(i,j)$, $1<i<j<n$.

Thank you

Comment: The eigenvalues are much easier to compute for generating sets closed under conjugation like $T$.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I find the eigenvalues of the reduced set S?

Comment: I don’t think there is any way to get the eigenvalues for the set S from T but I wouldn't be surprised if they are known.  The set S of generators is the set of Coxeter or Coxeter-Moore generators.  You can't immediately  get the eigenvalues just using character theory because S is not in the center of the group algebra

Comment: Many many thanks